# Pi Zero BOM component temperature range concern

Tags: temperature, pi-zero

I want to buy quite a few the Pi zero boards for outdoor use. Can you help get the BOM if possible, I want to confirm the temperature range for each component (the 19.2Mhz crystal, the caps and so on).

Comment: I doubt that information is available.  Have you tried the manufacturers?  Although I doubt they would be interested in answering unless you plan to order hundreds of thousands.

Comment: I also doubt that special concers where taken during design to pick components for a larger temperature range, given the key aspects of the Pi: **low cost and educational use**.. (But still a valid question. If the Pi's are delivered, people could at least try to figure out what components are used,)

Comment: Wouldn't this be better addressed by the source either the manufacturer as Joan mentioned or the Pi foundation?

Comment: The manufacturers shouldn't be telling product specs to third parties such as the OP. The foundation could at least state the design spec of the whole product - I don't know how supportive they are known to be in such matters.